# How to test form controls avoiding bracket notation to preserve type checking and maintainability

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-forms, form-control

#### The Problem

My unit tests on a form break when I refactor an object's member because I can only access the formcontrols on a fromgroup by using bracket notation. This string based selection of the member under test will not get refactored with the code by any IDE.

Here's an example...

The object:

```js
class Task {
  constructor(
    public id: number = 0,
    public description: string = '',    // <--- member under test
    public completed: boolean = false,
    public priority: Priority = Priority.Normal
  ) {}

  clone(): Task {
    return new Task(this.id, this.description, this.completed, this.priority);
  }
}
```

The component:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;
  task: Task;
  priorities = [Priority.Low, Priority.Normal, Priority.High];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.task = this.mockTask();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.task = this.mockTask();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      description: [
        this.task.description,
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      ],
      priority: [this.task.priority],
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

The test:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let comp: AppComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let task: Task;
  let taskService: TaskService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [{provide: TaskService, useClass: MockTaskService}]
    }).compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach((done) => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    taskService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TaskService);
    taskService.getAllTasks().subscribe(tasks => {
      task = tasks[0];
      comp.task = task;
      comp.ngOnInit();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      done()
    })
  })

  it('should not update value if form is invalid', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(taskService, 'updateTask')

    comp.form.controls['description'].setValue(null) // <------

    comp.onSubmit()

    expect(comp.form.valid).toBeFalsy();
    expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

Note the bracket notation next to the arrow. I would like to be able to use this somehow:

```
comp.form.controls.description.setValue(null)
```

#### What I Have Tried

I have tried creating some interface, e.g:

```js
interface ITask {
  description: string;
}

interface ITaskFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  value: ITask;
  controls: {
    description: AbstractControl;
  };
}
```

The problem with this is the controls are of type AbstractControl and the member of Task in question is of type string. So 'controls' can't implement ITask as a common interface.

Also, this:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    // ...
}
```

... allows for a dot-notation, but that would still not refactor the test when I change the member 'description' in Task or ITask.

I feel like this problem should have some solution, but I could use some help getting there. I would like to know what effort it would take so I can see if it is worth it in the long run.

#### Full Example

Although I don't think you can use a Test runner on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bddslj?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts), I provided a more complete example. To solve the syntax problem running the test should not be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of getting a form control from a FormGroup is to use its `get` function:

```
const descControl = comp.form.get('description')
descControl.setValue(null)
```

this way if the form control is missing, at least your tests will raise an error about it.

The angular team has implemented [strong typed forms](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43834). That can also help you with improving testing if you have the patience to wait for angular 14.